# How to compute the routing through N addresses/coordinates?

Tags: open-source-gis, routing

I have a set of *N* coordinates (addresses). My goal is to compute the shortest driving route through the set of coordinates, where the algorithm (not the user) decides which of the *N* coordinates should be the start point and which of the *N - 1* coordinates (excluding the start point) should be the end point.

**Can this be done and which algorithms are used for this kind of routing?**

By assuming that the routing can be done using the arial distance between the coordinates instead of roads, **how could I then solve my problem?**

*At this stage of my questioning, I am trying to determine how to solve the problem in theory but the tools at hand are a PostGIS database and anything I can implement my self in C# .NET. If any free libraries can help me, then they can be considered too :)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Travelling Salesman is supported by pgRouting: http://www.pgrouting.org/docs/1.x/index.html, so no need to implement something yourself if you alread have PostGIS at hand.

Answer (score 4):

This is known as the [Travelling Salesman Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem). To do want you want, you would probably first calculate all your driving distances between the N points, then use one of the known algorithms to solve the problem.